# Parabola touches the sides of a triangle tangents involved

Tags: tangent-line, parabolic-pde

A parabola touches the sides of a triangle ABC in the points D, E, and F respectively; if DE and DF cut the diameter through the point A in b and c respectively, prove that Bb and Cc are parallel

Comment: I made the parabola then 3 lines which are touching it on D E and F then there is a diameter which is passing through a and we know that diameter is parallel to x-axis then I took the equations of the three tangent Then solved for 3 points, they are intersecting and I got the coordinates of a it's X and Y co-ordinate then Y co-ordinate is the equation of the diameter

Comment: Are u getting me

Comment: I am asking you David Quinnin

Comment: can you draw a picture?

Comment: By “touches the sides” do you mean that the parabola is tangent to all three sides of the triangle? How can that be?

Comment: Yeah touches mean tangent

Comment: Do you know what is diameter of a parabola

Comment: @DavidQuinn picture isn't uploading